# Iterative spark with caching runs out of memory

Tags: apache-spark, caching, out-of-memory, checkpoint

I have a tiny pyspark dataframe with relations and a function that calculates the transitive closure. I know already a couple of ways in which I can improve the function (including getting rid of the `groupBy`), but let's stick with this.  When I iteratively apply the closure function, the computation time increases exponentially and spark even runs out of heap memory.

```
from pyspark.sql.dataframe import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, min

def closure(eq: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
    eqrev = eq.select(col("ID2").alias("ID1"), col("ID1").alias("ID2"))
    bi = eq.union(eqrev).distinct().cache()

    oldCount = 0
    nextCount = bi.count()

    while True:
        oldCount = nextCount
        newEdges = bi.alias("b1").join(bi.alias("b2"), col("b1.ID1") == col("b2.ID1")).select(col("b1.ID2").alias("ID1"), col("b2.ID2"))
        bi = bi.union(newEdges).distinct().cache()
        nextCount = bi.count()
        if nextCount == oldCount:
            break

    return bi.alias("b1").filter(col("b1.ID1") > col("b1.ID2")).groupBy("ID1").agg(min("ID2").alias("ID2")).cache()

b0 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([[ 22, 18 ], [ 20, 15] , [ 25, 26], [ 25, 29 ]], [ "ID1", "ID2" ])

b1 = closure(b0)
display(b1)
b2 = closure(b1)
display(b2)
b3 = closure(b2)
display(b3)
b4 = closure(b3)
```

`b1`, `b2`, `b3` all have 4 rows and 200 partitions (which are introduced by the `join`).  The execution plan grows linearly: for `b4` it is 13 stages. 
On my small cluster, the computation of `b2` takes 8 seconds, `b3` takes 40 seconds and `b4` gives a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` after a few minutes.

I would have expected that, given that I'm caching the result of each closure, the spark engine would be able to work this out.

Some related articles:

- [Spark iteration time increasing exponentially when using join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31659404/spark-iteration-time-increasing-exponentially-when-using-join) : the approved answer there is saying that the number of partitions is growing exponentially. But this is not the case for me. It stays at 200.
- [spark out of memory multiple iterations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40345809/spark-out-of-memory-multiple-iterations) : it is suggested to use `localCheckpoint`

If I change `.cache()` in the last line of the function to `.localCheckpoint()`, I do not get increasing execution time nor an out-of-memory exception. The documentation of `localCheckPoint) says: *Checkpointing can be used to truncate the logical plan of this DataFrame, which is especially useful in iterative algorithms where the plan may grow exponentially. Local checkpoints are stored in the executors using the caching subsystem and therefore they are not reliable.*

I now have the following questions:

- I'm already running into trouble with 4 iterations with almost no data. Is that really to be expected?
- Why is the computation time increasing so rapidly and why is the engine running out of heap space?  The execution plan still fits on my screen.
- What are the repercussions of using `localCheckPoint` in case of failures?

Comment: A known issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-25380

Comment: @NirHedvat Is this the same issue? SPARK-25380 talks about many iterations of the same code (I still think 4 is not many).  And it talks about plans that, in string form, occupies a large amount of space. This is not the case for me.  Also, then I'm still confused why, aside from running out of memory, the computation time increases so rapidly, given that I'm caching the previous result.